# WordPress query very slow on +/- 300k DB entries and 7 INNER JOIN

Tags: wp-query, query, mysql

So here's the situation, we have a WP DB that has +/- 300k posts, and there is a complex query that has to be done checking different metas and crossing different info, etc. Here's the query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS sr_posts.ID FROM sr_posts
LEFT JOIN sr_term_relationships ON (sr_posts.ID = sr_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN sr_postmeta ON ( sr_posts.ID = sr_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt3.post_id )
INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt4 ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt4.post_id )
INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt5 ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt5.post_id )
INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt6 ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt6.post_id )
WHERE 1=1 AND ( sr_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1293,1294,1295) ) AND ( ( sr_postmeta.meta_key = '_start_price' AND CAST(sr_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0' AND '99999' ) AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'event_upto_date' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20170723' ) OR ( ( mt2.meta_key = 'event_end_date_comp' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20170723' ) AND ( mt3.meta_key = 'event_end_date_comp' AND mt3.meta_value != '' ) ) ) AND ( ( ( mt4.meta_key = 'event_upto_date' AND CAST(mt4.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20170722' ) OR ( mt4.meta_key = 'event_end_date_comp' AND CAST(mt4.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20170722' ) ) ) AND ( mt5.meta_key = 'is_single_day_event' AND mt6.meta_key = 'event_upto_date' ) ) AND sr_posts.post_type = 'event' AND ((sr_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY sr_posts.ID ORDER BY CAST(mt6.meta_value AS CHAR) ASC, CAST(mt5.meta_value AS CHAR) DESC LIMIT 0, 18
```

We first tried to optimize code, the way WP creates this query (we are using WP_Query, not working with custom queries). Not suceeded!

Then we tried investigate further and used the "Profile" on phpMyAdmin and saw that, from the total 65.8516 seconds that it was taking, 65 seconds was in "Storing Result In Query Cache".

We then searched and found out two possible outcomes:

1. Increase available memory for query_cache (we raised from 80M to 256M);
2. Completely deactivate query_cache.

None did anything whatsoever... query continued exactly the same!

So here I am, asking for help from some captain out there! :)

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT 1:

I could reduce the query time to 17 seconds just by removing this:

```
GROUP BY sr_posts.ID ORDER BY CAST(mt6.meta_value AS CHAR) ASC, CAST(mt5.meta_value AS CHAR) DESC LIMIT 0, 18
```

Problem is... I obviously need this! :P

EDIT 2:

CAST could be the culprit here, but in this case it's not, since I removed and it did nothing... keeps loading in results between 63 and 67 seconds.

EDIT 3 (my answer to my own problem):

And here's the reason why this was slow, in short, problem was that instead of "filtering" immediately on INNER JOINs, I was doing it on WHERE, which caused the query to be MUCH slower. So here's the proper query:

```
SELECT
 SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS sr_posts.ID
FROM sr_posts
 LEFT JOIN sr_term_relationships
  ON (sr_posts.ID = sr_term_relationships.object_id)
 INNER JOIN sr_postmeta
  ON ( sr_posts.ID = sr_postmeta.post_id )
 INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt1
  ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) AND mt1.meta_key = 'event_upto_date'
 INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt2
  ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) AND mt2.meta_key = 'event_end_date_comp'
 INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt3
  ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt3.post_id ) AND mt3.meta_key = 'event_end_date_comp'
 INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt4
  ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt4.post_id )
 INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt5
  ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt5.post_id ) AND mt5.meta_key = 'is_single_day_event'
 INNER JOIN sr_postmeta AS mt6
  ON ( sr_posts.ID = mt6.post_id ) AND mt6.meta_key = 'event_upto_date'
WHERE
 sr_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1293,1294,1295) AND
 ( ( sr_postmeta.meta_key = '_start_price' AND CAST(sr_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0' AND '99999' ) AND ( ( CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20170723' ) OR ( ( CAST(mt2.meta_value AS SIGNED) <= '20170723' ) AND ( mt3.meta_value != '' ) ) ) AND ( ( ( mt4.meta_key = 'event_upto_date' AND CAST(mt4.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20170722' ) OR ( mt4.meta_key = 'event_end_date_comp' AND CAST(mt4.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '20170722' ) ) ) ) AND
 sr_posts.post_type = 'event' AND
 sr_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY
 sr_posts.ID
ORDER BY
 CAST(mt6.meta_value AS CHAR) ASC,
 CAST(mt5.meta_value AS CHAR) DESC
LIMIT 0, 18
```

This query takes +/- 1 second... compared to 67 seconds, it's a "small difference" :D

Comment: sorry, but this is not an actual question. you have a lot of data so obviously it will take time to query it. The solution is to restructure the way you store data in the DB. pro tip: using meta in queries leads to bad performance, and you should use taxonomies whenever possible.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I honestly swear I don't know how to put this "as a question". I look at it and I see a question there, but it seems I just don't know how to make questions since this is not the first nor the second time someone downvote a "suposed question of mine". :(
Well, anyway, thanks a lot for your tips, it definitely helps already and I will have a closer looko on that. :)

Comment: Not looking at your other questions, but this is a Q&A site and not a forum, and a question should lead to an authoritative answer and not just guesses or general suggestions/tips. Some things like "suggest me better way" just do not fit this format very well unless it is a very focused issue. In this case without knowing what is in your DB it is very hard to suggest anything which is not just too broad to be very useful

Comment: Makes total sense what you are saying. I will keep that in mind for future reference. Thanks. :) Anyway, I just found the problem and I posted the result, so in case someone in the future face the same problem, can find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically: Not every kind of data fits well into the WordPress meta model. Sometimes, you'd be better off making a custom set of tables for your data.

If you have to query against 7 different meta values and a taxonomy, then perhaps a custom post type is not the best way to store your data.

The WordPress model is designed for fast retrieval of posts and their associated meta based on a very limited set of selection results. It *supports* ways of selecting via meta data, but that is not optimal nor is the data model optimized for it. It's never going to be "fast" to do so. Not really.

So, if you need to select by a whole lot of different fields which aren't normal "post" fields, then you might want to just make an entirely new table for your data, with columns for those fields, and proper indexing on them, and so forth. If you're having to create your own crazy SQL already, then making a new table and managing your own data is likely actually *easier* than screwing around with a Custom Post Type.

As for security, using the built in wpdb::insert and wpdb:update functions will let you do statements securely and without having to do a whole lot of your own calls to wpdb::prepare or writing a whole lot of your own SQL. They even work with your own custom tables.

Comment: Thanks @Otto what you say makes total sense and we are now more aware of the limitations of WordPress. Though, this is something that in my opinion, is just ridiculous because it's just a matter of creating a better query, which WP should do because the way it creates the query originally, it's the main problem that makes it slow (as we could clearly see in my example). With the changed query that I have there, sometimes I get the results in under a second, which is perfectly normal for me hence the number of posts and things it has to do before delivering the results. :)

Comment: The "changed query" you have there isn't better, it's simply insane. No system would generate such a convoluted thing. The fact that you have to use something that complex shows that the data does not fit into the system you have fit it into. Like I said, not everything fits the WordPress meta-model properly. Square plug, round hole, and you've used a hammer.

Comment: Even so, the difference is very clear on the response times. In this specific case, if it would be easy to change the structure of the DB at this time, believe me that I would be the first one to do it, but that would mean changin A LOT of things! Almost re-doing everything again... So in this particular case, the improvement was insanely great and it works, so we leave it like that. :)